# Javascript and a href

Tags: javascript, html, href

Let's suppose that I have the following dropdown after the last div, a dropdown menu appears once he clicks.

```
<div id="test"> <a href="clickthrough.php">Arrow</a> </div>
```

I want the user to be able to click on this element and the dropdown appear but also if he mid clicks to be able to open this link directly in a new tab. In other words I want to prevent the default action onclick but still show the link of the element on hover or whatever.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do

```
<div id="test"> <a href="clickthrough.php" onclick="FunctionForOpeningLink();return false;">Arrow</a> </div>
```

Comment: Pass the URL to the function and return an appropriate value: `... onclick="return FunctionForOpeningLink(this.href);" ...` then have *FunctionForOpeningLink* return false if it's happy, if not return undefined and the link will be followed.

Answer (score -1):

with jquery 1.7+

```
$('#test a').on('click', function (e) {
  if (e.which < 2) { // left mouse button
    e.preventDefault();
    // and code to show dropdown
  }
});
```